# i need a background image to change on menu text hover css

Tags: menu, hover, background-image

/*add background image*/
body #page-container
.et_slide_in_menu_container
{
background: url('https://24hr-locksmith.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/pexels-paloma-clarice-2802688-scaled-1.jpg') center center !important;
background-size: cover !important;}

.site-footer > .site-info { display: none; }

/*add background image on hover*/
#menu-item-538:hover

{
background: url('https://24hr-locksmith.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/pexels-photo-775201.jpg') center center !important;

```
background-size: cover 
        !important;
```

}

Comment: https://24hr-locksmith.co.uk/

Comment: please can someone help me change the background of the fullscreen menu when the menu links are hovered over. thank you

Comment: i have managed to get the menu items background to change on hover but not the full screen background